# What framework to use for advanced job scheduling in Java?

Tags: java, scheduling, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch-admin

In my application I need to have periodically run background tasks (which I can easily do with Quartz - i.e. schedule a given job to be run at a specific time periodically).

But I would like to have a little bit more control. In particular I need to:

1. have the system rerun a task that wasn't run at its scheduled time (i.e. the server was down and because of this the task was not run. In such a situation I want the 'late' task to be run ASAP)
2. it would be nice to easily control tasks - i.e. run a task on demand or see when a given task was last run or reschedule a given task to be run at a different time

It seems to me that the above points can be achieved with Spring Batch Admin, but I don't have much experience in this area yet. Also, I've seen numerous posts on how Spring Batch is not a scheduling tool so I'm becoming to have doubts what the right tool for the job is here.

So my question is: can the above be achieved with Spring Batch Admin? Or perhaps Quartz is enough but needs configuring to do the above? Or maybe I need both? Or something else?

Thanks a lot :)
Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> have the system rerun a task that wasn't run at its scheduled time

This feature in [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is called [*Misfire Instructions*](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-04) and does exactly what you need - but is a lot more flexible. All you need is to define [`JDBCJobStore`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09).

> it would be nice to easily control tasks - i.e. run a task on demand or see when a given task was last run or reschedule a given task to be run at a different time

You can use Quartz [JMX](http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/QUARTZ-300) to access various information (like previous and next run time) or query the Quartz database tables directly. There are also free and commercial management tools basex on the above input. I believe you can also manually run jobs there.

[Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) can be **integrated** with Quartz, but not replace it.